# Signed apk, gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to create a signed apk and I get these errors:

> Error:Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error:A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       L:\Program Files\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output L:\Projects\AndroidStd\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\release\classes-39ba3836d4c6583346af78c04589394ab9d91ac9.jar L:\Projects\AndroidStd\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\20.0.0\classes.jar
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>       Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I am using -Xms128m -Xmx128m parameters in gradle and I have used many combinations too but nothing worked. Thank you for your help in advance.